# My ngx-translator is not able to get the Current language in Ionic4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am using the ngx-translator package but it is not able to set the defaultlangaue in my app.

This is my **app.module.ts**:

```
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, "./assets/i18n/", ".json");
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
          provide: TranslateLoader,
          useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
          deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    }),
    AppRoutingModule, HttpClientModule],
    providers: [
    StatusBar,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

This is my **app.component.ts**:

```
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
constructor(private translate: TranslateService) {
    this.initializeApp();
    this.translate.setDefaultLang('en');
    }
```

This is my **tab1.page.ts**:

```
 import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
 language: string = this.translate.currentLang;
 constructor(private translate: TranslateService) { 
 console.log('Default language:', this.translate.currentLang);
 }
```

When I console the `console.log('Default language:', this.translate.currentLang);`, it is showing undefined in the console.

This is my **customcomponent.component.html**:

```
  <ion-select (ionChange)='setLanguage()'>
  <ion-select-option value='en' selected='true'>English</ion-select-option>
  <ion-select-option value='ar'>Arabic</ion-select-option>
  </ion-select>
```

I just to show the selected language in the selected box but my currentlang is not working.

When I printed the current Lang, it is showing undefined.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I also faced same issue. Just change app.component.ts

From

```
this.translate.setDefaultLang('en');
```

To

```
this.translate.use('en');
```

In my case :

I have created services(provider) like this

```
public changeLanguage(langCode:string){
   this.translate.use(langCode);
}
```

Just pass language name in function from any component

```
this.serviceProvider.changeLanguage("en");
```

Comment: Okay, I have one question that, I have the select box for changing the language in the custom component in Ionic and I am setting the default language in the custom component but It is not showing the language in the app. Do I have to set language in the app.component.ts only.

Comment: I have to use the setDefaultLang and use in the app.component.ts only or I can use on any component.ts file.

Comment: yes you can change language anywhere. any component

Comment: But this is not happening, I am changing the language in my customcomponent.component.ts file but It is not changing the language.

Comment: have you included customcomponent in app module or are you using lazy loading

Comment: I have created one service and using everywhere to change language.

Comment: Okay but I am changing the language from the customcomponent because I want to show the same language in the whole app.

Comment: And I have not included the customcomponent in my app.module.ts and I have included in each page module.ts

Comment: Okay. I will try. Thank you for the answer.